# Using debuild to build rpi-imager, I see an error finding Qt5.14 or better

Tags: linux, cmake, qt5, raspberry-pi4

I'm running debuild on Debian 10 to build rpi-imager, and it's failing to find Qt5.14 (or better):

```
/rpi-imager$ debuild -uc -us -d
 dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -d
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package rpi-imager
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 1.8.1
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by Floris Bos <bos@je-eigen-domein.nl>
 dpkg-source --before-build .
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --sourcedirectory=src
   dh_auto_clean -O--sourcedirectory=src
   dh_autoreconf_clean -O--sourcedirectory=src
   dh_clean -O--sourcedirectory=src
 dpkg-source -b .
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (native)'
dpkg-source: info: building rpi-imager in rpi-imager_1.8.1.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: building rpi-imager in rpi-imager_1.8.1.dsc
 debian/rules build
make: 'build' is up to date.
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh binary --sourcedirectory=src
   dh_update_autotools_config -O--sourcedirectory=src
   dh_autoreconf -O--sourcedirectory=src
   dh_auto_configure -O--sourcedirectory=src
        cd obj-x86_64-linux-gnu && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR=/etc -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALSTATEDIR=/var -DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON -DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON "-GUnix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ../src
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:110 (message):
  Missing suitable Qt library (must be at least version 5.14)
```

But Qt is avaliable at `/usr/local/Qt-5.15.2/`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     640 Nov 27 17:16 /usr/local/Qt-5.15.2/lib/libQt5Core.la
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1284 Nov 27 17:16 /usr/local/Qt-5.15.2/lib/libQt5Core.prl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Nov 27 17:16 /usr/local/Qt-5.15.2/lib/libQt5Core.so -> libQt5Core.so.5.15.2*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Nov 27 17:16 /usr/local/Qt-5.15.2/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 -> libQt5Core.so.5.15.2*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Nov 27 17:16 /usr/local/Qt-5.15.2/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15 -> libQt5Core.so.5.15.2*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 6207832 Nov 27 17:16 /usr/local/Qt-5.15.2/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.15.2*
```

(The rest [?] of the libraries are there as well -- this is just an illustration. They reside there as a result of running `make install` when building Qt5.15.)

I've tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`, and `DEB_LIBRARY_PATH` (I'm not even sure that last one means anything to anything, tbh), and nothing changed.

How do I get debuild to recognize the location of the libraries? I've got Qt5.11 installed in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, so it's possible that's what it's finding.

UPDATE: I've added the libraries to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (supplanting the 5.11 versions), to no effect.